# I need to get some information form the cisco device. It is cisco-ios-xe device

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, ietf-netmod-yang, ietf-netconf, ietf-restconf

I have a CISCO device. The device is configured with the WebUI. Which have many details? But I am not able to get these following details from there.

1. CPU Load
2. Temperature
3. Device details.
4. Memory use
5. Alarms

I have tried many times to get those above define values. But not able to get any things, Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the model & software version, the web UI can vary. You'll have better luck obtaining those details utilising CLI instead.

Whilst the CLI is fairly consistent between models/software versions, some commands might not be available. Consulting the Cisco documentation for your specific hardware & software revisions should help.

> CPU Load

**`show processes cpu history`**
Will show you the CPU usage over 60 seconds, 1 hour and 72 hours.

**`show processes cpu`**
Will show you the running processes with the CPU utilisation over 5 seconds, 1 minute and 5 minutes.

> Temperature

**`show environment all`**
**`show environment temperature`**
Outputs all the environmental conditions including power & temperature. You'll find the temperatures within the temperature section .

> Device details.

**`show version`**
Displays the core information about your device & software. This includes the hardware details, IOS & ROM software versions, interfaces & memory, and system uptime/previous reload reason.

**`show inventory`**
Will output details about any additional hardware installed into your device, such as SFP, their type & serial numbers.

> Memory use

**`show processes memory`**
Whilst `show version` shows you the total memory installed into your device, `show processes memory` shows you how it's being utilised, by which process, and how much is remaining.

**`show flash:`** / **`show bootflash`**
Will show you the files being stored into the flash memory, their sizes & how much space is left.

> Alarms

**`show alarms`** / **`show facility-alarm status`**
If your equipment has an alarm indicator, the above commands will show advise you what's alarmed & the reasoning.